# How do I use information from Roblox Games API?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am trying to make some code that gets information about games using the Roblox API. I do get data back when I send a request, but I can't figure out a way to use the data in the code. Because when I decode it, it looks like this:

```
{
                    ["data"] =  ▼  {
                       [1] =  ▼  {
                          ["allowedGearCategories"] = {},
                          ["allowedGearGenres"] =  ▶ {...},
                          ["copyingAllowed"] = false,
                          ["createVipServersAllowed"] = false,
                          ["created"] = <creation date>,
                          ["creator"] =  ▶ {...},
                          ["description"] = "",
                          ["favoritedCount"] = 0,
                          ["genre"] = "Comedy",
                          ["id"] = <the id>,
                          ["isAllGenre"] = false,
                          ["isFavoritedByUser"] = false,
                          ["isGenreEnforced"] = true,
                          ["maxPlayers"] = 10,
                          ["name"] = <the name>,
                          ["playing"] = 0,
                          ["rootPlaceId"] = <the id>,
                          ["studioAccessToApisAllowed"] = false,
                          ["universeAvatarType"] = "PlayerChoice",
                          ["updated"] = <update date>,
                          ["visits"] = 0
                       }
                    }
                 }
```

I censored some of the information about which game it is, but that information isn't important here. The important thing is that it says "1" under "data", and if I type that into the code, it uses it as a number. So I can't access anything further down in the list than "data".

Here is my code, if it helps:

```
local universe = Proxy:Get("https://api.roblox.com/universes/get-universe-containing-place?placeid="..placeId).body
local universeDecoded = http:JSONDecode(universe)
local universeId = universeDecoded.UniverseId

local placeInfo = http:JSONDecode(Proxy:Get("https://games.roblox.com/v1/games?universeIds="..universeId).body) 
print(placeInfo.data)
```

Also, sorry for not knowing a lot of programming words, so I say stuff like "further down in the list". But I hope it's clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I just had to write

```
print(placeInfo.data[1])
```